how to add span custom attribute to automatic span created when sending request with `io. vertx. core. http.HttpClientRequest`
I'm asked to add custom span attributes to http opentelemetry spans that vertx creates automatically.
Somewhere in the code, I've identified a io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientRequest instance that execute the method send(). Just before that code, I tried to get and update the current span using io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span.current().setAttribute('key', 'value') but it does not work.
Any help or link that explains "how to" will be welcome.
Thanks a lot
Regards
